# What does "the firmament of the body" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, literature

[image]

Many dictionaries define "the firmament" as the sky. OK

But I don't understand the word "the firmament of the body" at all.

What does it mean..?

Comment: This is not really a question about English. You should ask a philosopher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Firmament" is a mistranslation from the King James Bible, for a Hebrew word meaning "expanse (of the sky or the ground)"

Here it means, by extension "God created thing", and so refers to the body as being like figuratively like the heavens, because it is created by God.